# Declare a different android:name in Manifest

Tags: android

I´m trying to use a global variable. I got this doing the next:

1/ First I create this class

```
package ar.ncantarini.mapa;

import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    int id_mascota;

    public int getId_mascota() {
        return id_mascota;
    }

    public void setId_mascota(int id_mascota) {
        this.id_mascota = id_mascota;
    }

}
```

2/ In some Activity I put:

```
// Calling Application class (see application tag in AndroidManifest.xml)
final MyApplication globalVariable = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();

//Set name and email in global/application context
globalVariable.setId_mascota(1);
```

3/ In other Activity I do:

```
//  Calling Application class (see application tag in AndroidManifest.xml)

final MyApplication globalVariable = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();

// Get name and email from global/application context
final int name  = globalVariable.getId_mascota();

//inside a method
```

4/ At last, In the Manifest I add the android name tag.

```
   <application

    android:name=".MyApplication" 
     android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <activity
```

Every thing works well. But my problem is that now I need to move the "MyApplication" class to another packcage calls "Utilities" which is not the 
    "main" packcage of the android app.

After move this class, I have test change the manifest like that:

```
1_android:name="Utilities.MyApplication" 
2_android:name="Utilities$MyApplication" 
3_android:name=".Utilities.MyApplication"
```

And always I have the " no source find" error. The same problem is in another project when a use de "BroadcasteReceiver" class, and when I put this in a packcage that isnt the main packcage. In my case my main packcage is ar.ncantarini.mapa.

EDIT: here I add a photo of the error I always have, when I move the MyApplication class to the Utilities packcage .

[image]

Comment: Use your Application class as a single class...there´s no need for all the cleaness. By the way, you can add the whole package name to the class spec in the xml for in case there´s a problem with that

Comment: Sorry but how it would be use my Application as singles class? whay is means? Do you have an code example?

Comment: as I understood you was putting the Application class within another class

Comment: Yes, Application class is alone. It is a ordinary class. I dont understand, what is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the @MarcosVasconcelos answers, I combine them, and I arrived to a solution. The key is that the name of the package in Android should be in lowercase. that´s all.

Answer (score 0):

At your manifest, starting a declaration with a dot (.) you are referencing the main package, you can also declare the full name of your Activity class.

In your case, its just:

```
android:name="Utilities.MyApplication"
```

Please note, that package names is encouraged to be full lowercase.

Comment: The full name for this case, would be : Utilities.MyApplication, if I´m not wrong. Check the link please. Look at my estructure project. But I think i´m right. I dont know what more do : (

Comment: Yes, it's exactly Utilities.MyApplication, it does not work? Note that you should not add the dot before this declaration.

Comment: No it doesnt work! Please, look at my post: "after move this class, I have test change the manifiest like that:

1_android:name="Utilities.MyApplication"      "

Comment: Well, then your code should work. For a try, I would name the package in lower case.

Comment: When you create a packcage in Eclipse IDE, it must start with a uppercace.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos, By the way, I tried this, and didnt works.

Comment: Wait, wait. I find something. If I put in my Manifiest : android:name="utilities.MyApplication" it didnt work. But when I also refactor my packcage name form Utilities to utilities, its works!. But I dont understand why it doest work with Utilities as the name of the packcage and  android:name="Utilities.MyApplication". Its rare. It will be a Eclipse bug?

Comment: First, eclipse dont ask for a uppercase.

Second, probably its a android limitation.

Comment: I think you @MarcosVasconcelos always know it. "  
Nah.. hes in a uppercased package. –  Marcos Vasconcelos 16 hours ago"     well, by the way, thank you fto every body!